# Angular routerlink routes wrong in test

Tags: angular, testing, angular-routerlink

I try to test a routerlink click that should route from /parent to /parent/child in the root router-outlet. When i start my application **everything works**, but in my test i get this error message:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'child'

My routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ParentComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'parent/child',
    component: ChildComponent
  }

];
```

HTML on parent (/parent) that should route to /parent/child

```
<a routerLink="./child">child</a>
```

this works aswell but not in test:

```
<a routerLink="child">child</a>
```

My test:

```
describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
        AppModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('router to child test', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigate(["/parent"]);
    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe("/parent")
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("a")).nativeElement.click();
    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe("/parent/child");
  }));
});
```

The route itself is there, because when i try something like this, it works:

```
 it('router to child test', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigate(["/parent"]);
    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe("/parent")
    //fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("a")).nativeElement.click();
    router.navigate(["/parent/child"]);

    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe("/parent/child");
  }));
```

It seems that my test cant handle the routerLink directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to test Angular's inner workings.

Instead what would be enough is to check if the element has the correct attribute value in `routerLink` and trust the framework to do the right thing.

Something like this:

```
  it('renders the correct routerLink attribute to the child component', () => {
    const anchor = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a'));

    expect(anchor.nativeElement.getAttribute('routerLink')).toEqual('./child');
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Yes, during unit testing the child route is not added to the parent route.

`router.navigate(['./child']); // <-- not working`

now let's go back to your original implementation:

`router.navigate(["/parent/child"]); // <-- it works`

now to make it work from your html you can change the `routerLink` attribute to this:

`<a routerLink="/parent/child">child</a>`

now your unit test will pass.

```
  it('router to child test', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigate(['/parent']);
    tick();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/parent');

    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement.click();    
    tick();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/parent/child');
  }));
```

Also note the `children` attribute on route configuration to create true child routes. Something like this:

```
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: i understand your argumentation. I think its a little bit confusing because when i call a routerlink with /parent it works. But i cant route from /parent to /parent/child in my test because the test router module doesnt recognize that he should add /child to the current /parent route. Is this right? And there is no possibility to do this?

Comment: thanks for edit .... Having the whole link at once like /parent/child only for testing is not so nice for me because i want use child in different parents but i will stick to your first solution now. Thank you.